# How to make a div refresh?

Tags: javascript, php

So this is my button div inside a PHP function called getDetails().

```
<div class='detail_cart'>
<a href='detail.php?add_cart=$prod_id'>
<button id='detail_button_add'>Add to cart</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Based on ip address, it counts how many products you've added in the cart and display them to my shop cart icon. 

Every time the button is pressed it adds the product into a database but i need refresh page in order to see the updated count.

```
 echo "<div id ='total_cart'>";
 echo $count_cart =mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
 echo "</div>";
```

I tried to fix but no chance..

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#detail_button_add").bind("click",function(){
        $("#total_cart").load("header.php");
    });
});

</script>
```

"header.php" is the header section of my PHP.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console of the browser's developer tools?

Comment: No, it's just annoying becouse i need to refresh the page in order to see the updated cart..

Comment: Put some debug code in the function that you are binding to make sure it is being invoked. Also, the third parameter to `load()` is an optional callback function that you can use to see what is being sent from the server.

Comment: Also, you've got a button inside a link. Are you cancelling the link when the button is pressed, because your browser should naturally be navigating to the target. I'm also wondering if there's a potential race condition somehow.

Comment: "*Based on ip address*" You shouldn't identify users by IP. Multiple users can have the same IP, and IP can change and the user then loses the cart.

Comment: You didn't really explain what happens instead of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an clear div with an `span` inside. You will get the data from an API in this case your header.php that returns 1,2 or any number and that will be displayed.

Your header.php

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
http_response_code(200);
exit;
```

```html
<div id="total_cart">
    <span id="total_cart_num"></span>
</div>

 <div>
  <a href="detail.php?add_cart=<?=$prod_id ?>">
    <button id="detail_button_add">Add to cart</button>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelector("#detail_button_add").addEventListener("click", function(){
        refreshCart();
    });

    function refreshCart(){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Add link to your Site that returns the count
        xhr.open("GET", "header.php"); // Header returns Like 1,2,3 or any Number

        xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                document.querySelector("#total_cart_num").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            } else {
                alert("An error as been triggered!");
            }
        });
        xhr.send();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: He is using jQuery. Why not use that for AJAX and event binding? And why a new element instead of inserting into #total_cart?

Comment: Yeah but why he cant use Js for that i see there no problem or can you explain why is it better to use jquery

Comment: "*why is it better to use jquery*" A lot less code. It took you 12 lines of code to do jQuery's single line `$("#total_cart").load("header.php");`. There is no point in reimplementing jQuery's functionality if you already use jQuery.

Comment: And you didn't really solve his problem. putting a div inside another div, doesn't prevent it from showing up, even if they have the same id.

Comment: Well you removed the link, which is probably the actual problem. But I assume he needs it.

Comment: `<a href='detail.php?add_cart=$prod_id'>`

Comment: Oh I know his problem his URL `<a href='detail.php?add_cart=$prod_id'>` the ´$prod_id´ coud not be displayed solution `<a href='detail.php?add_cart=<?=$prod_id ?>'>`

Comment: I noticed that your code snippet does not work. Please make sure it works or remove it because as it is now that "run snippet code" does not help anyone.

Comment: How can i display code better without the "run code" button ?c

Comment: @FabianSchuss - it does not work. I see "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure" when I press on the button.

Comment: Yeah beacuse here is here no "header.php" file you know ?

Comment: Please remove that snippet then because it does not help anybody wathing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**If you mean that this is header.php:**

```
echo "<div id ='total_cart'>";
echo $count_cart =mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
echo "</div>";
```

and you do this:

```
$("#total_cart").load("header.php");
```

the result would be:

```
<div id ='total_cart'>
{content from header.php}
</div>
```

e.g.

```
<div id ='total_cart'>
    <div id ='total_cart'>
    {count of cart}
    </div>
</div>
```

The solution is to skip the creation of div in the header.php:
(create that div elsewhere)

```
//remove echo "<div id ='total_cart'>";
echo $count_cart =mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
//remove echo "</div>";
```

If you don't get your click event to work, you might need to use **on**("click"... instead of **bind**("click"...
*(on also works on dynamically created html elements (with content))*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#detail_button_add").on("click",function(){
        //This header.php should NOT include the actual html-element (div) jsut the 
        //content you want INSIDE the htm-element with id #total_cart
        $("#total_cart").load("header.php");         
    });
});
```

Another thing with your first code-snippet is that your link won't work:

```
<a href='detail.php?add_cart=$prod_id'>
```

It should be (taking for granted you have the code in a php-file)

```
<a href='detail.php?add_cart=<?php echo $prod_id;?>'>
```

Comment: He also needs to call `event.preventDefault()`, otherwise he will navigate away. But he probably also needs to hit that URL.

Comment: @gre_gor - Thanks for your input! It depends on what OP want. The on-click is binded to the button though (and not the hyperlink).